# Scroll to anchor in Angular 6

Tags: angular, scroll, angular6, anchor

I'm trying to create an anchor on my "Angular 6" page, but when I add the configuration:

```
imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{'anchorScrolling': 'enabled',})],
```

it returns an error:

```
Unable to assign type '{anchorScrolling: string; scrollPositionRestoration: string; } 'to type' ExtraOptions'. An object literal can only specify known properties, and 'anchorScrolling' does not exist in the 'ExtraOptions' type.
```

Any idea?

Thank you!

Additional Info: My file is "app-routing-module.ts" and have info about routing:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule, ExtraOptions } from '@angular/router';

const routes: Routes = 
[
  { path: '', component: ComIdiomaurlComponent }
];

@NgModule
(
  {
    imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,{'anchorScrolling': 'enabled'})],
    exports: [RouterModule]
  }
)
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

The help from Visual Studio Code give me the next options to extraoptions:

```
Options (see ExtraOptions):
- enableTracing makes the router log all its internal events to the console.
- useHash enables the location strategy that uses the URL fragment instead of the history API.
- initialNavigation disables the initial navigation.
- errorHandler provides a custom error handler.
- preloadingStrategy configures a preloading strategy (see PreloadAllModules).
- onSameUrlNavigation configures how the router handles navigation to the current URL.

See ExtraOptions for more details.
```

Why does not it appear in other options?

This is my package.json:

```
{
"name": "gijon-main",
"version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@agm/snazzy-info-window": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "@angular/common": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome": "^0.1.1",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.1.0",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.0.0",
    "@ng-select/ng-select": "^2.1.3",
    "@ngx-share/button": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-share/buttons": "^6.0.1",
    "@ngx-share/core": "^6.0.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "angular2-cookie-law": "^6.0.4",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "cookieconsent": "^3.1.0",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "ng-bootstrap": "^1.6.3",
    "ng2-page-scroll": "^4.0.0-beta.12",
    "ng2-translate": "^5.0.0",
    "ngx-cookieconsent": "^2.0.0",
    "ngx-flickity": "0.0.9",
    "popper.js": "^1.14.3",
    "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.2.0",
    "snazzy-info-window": "^1.1.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.0",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.1.0",
    "@types/datatables.net": "^1.10.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.6",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "codelyzer": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~1.7.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~1.4.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.3.0",
    "ts-node": "~5.0.1",
    "tslint": "~5.9.1",
    "typescript": "~2.7.2"
  }
}
```

Comment: What is the rest of your ExtraOptions config ?

Comment: Ye, i believe it must work if you have version 6.1+, code is fine so far

Comment: I have added information about the file. Thank you to everyone

Comment: Can you also provide your `package.json` file? Most likely there is an issue there because, as others have pointed out, your code should work fine with the right version of Angular and the `@angular/router` package.

Comment: Added package.json

Answer (score 1):

I think than the problem is "Angular 6.0"....until Angular 6.1 there is no such option.

Answer (score 1):

The `anchorScrolling` feature was only introduced in [Angular 6.1.0](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#610-2018-07-25) by [49c5234](https://github.com/angular/angular/commit/49c5234).

You will have to update to Angular 6.1.0 to use this feature.

Comment: Using unmatching versions of individual Angular packages is not recommended and should be avoided. Even if it might work in the odd case you should always try to update all packages simultaneously.